# table align center not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome

I have created a table and filtering using dynatable plugin.Its all working fine but my problem is, my table aligning center in firefox when i use below code,

**CSS :**

```
table{max-width:100%;background-color:transparent;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
.table{width:80%;margin-bottom:20px;}.table th,.table td{padding:8px;line-height:20px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;border-top:1px solid #dddddd;}
.table th{font-weight:bold;}
.table-hover tbody tr:hover>td{background-color:#176940; color:white;}
```

**jsp :**

```
 <table id="my-table"  style="margin:auto;  border: thick solid black; text-align: left" border="1" >

      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Hobby</th>
          <th>Favorite Music</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Fred</td>
          <td>Roller Skating</td>
          <td>Disco</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Helen</td>
          <td>Rock Climbing</td>
          <td>Alternative</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Glen</td>
          <td>Traveling</td>
          <td>Classical</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

the table displays like below image,
[image]

but in chrome displays left alignment like below image,
[image]

Here is my fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Manivasagam/La196r4g/7/

Where i am wrong?

Comment: It is centered fine until the "Dynatable" button is clicked. Then it only works when the viewport is a certain small width. When the viewport gets too wide, something in the javascript is making a change which breaks your centering.

Comment: @misterManSam yes your are right.so tell me fix.

Answer (score 1):

Your search box top right has a height larger than the "Show: 10" box on the left. The table is aligned with the left side of this search box.

You can solve it by putting both "Show: 10" and "Search" boxes in a div, which has a height large enough to fit both.

Comment: i understand the problem but i dont know how to solve in that dynatable.js file.could you please fix this?